# Time schedular in java with Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

```
  import java.util.Date;

  import javax.xml.crypto.Data;

  public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      // run in a second
      final long timeInterval = 4000;
      Data now = null;
      Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          while (true) {
            // ------- code for task to run
            System.out.println("Hello !!"+new Date());
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
              System.out.println("Hello !!");
            }

            // ------- ends here
            try {
              Thread.sleep(timeInterval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
       }

      };

      Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
      thread.start();
    }
  }
```

I read a tutorial regarding the scheduling of threads.I want to understand that the code runs fine and executes thread after 4 seconds but if the time taken by for loop suppose comes out to be 1 second then total time will be 1+4 5 seconds.
I do not want to executor service .Just normal Thread class.Can anyone explain how this program is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that `sleep` is in addition to the time taken in the loop already.

Even if you calculated the sleep time remaining, it still could take longer as there is no guarantee as to how quickly sleep will wake up. It can be tens of milli-seconds later sometimes.

What ExecutorService does is calculate when it should wake from the first run and ensure any delays don't accumulate. It uses System.nanoTime() so corrections in the wall clock don't impact the period.

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview what will be best way to solve this to execute a thread after certain interval without executor

Comment: @coder25 obviously the best way is to use a ScheduledExecutorService, or do what it does which is take the System.nanoTime() at the start and calculate how long it should sleep for each time to avoid accumulated errors. If wall clock is what matters, you can use System.currentTimeMillis()